# I need help with an lxml statement in python that extracts a meta-tag value

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I need help fixing this lxml statement to extract the:
http://www.etc../1tru.jpg link in the head section of
http://www.yfrog.com/9d1truj

```
#This doesn't work!

# <link rel="image_src" href="http://img337.yfrog.com/img337/5023/1tru.jpg" />
def extract_imageurl(self, doc):
    try:
        self.url, = doc.xpath('//head//link[@rel="image_src"][1]/@href')
    except ValueError:
        self.url = "Error"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [32]: doc.xpath('//head/link[@rel="image_src"]/@href')[0]
Out[32]: 'http://img337.yfrog.com/img337/5023/1tru.jpg'
```

Notice `xpath` returns a list of nodes:

```
In [25]: doc.xpath('//head/link')
Out[25]: [<Element link at 9c94c5c>, <Element link at 9c94b6c>]
```

Once you've specified `[@rel="image_src"]` there is only one node in the list.
You can pick off the node with `[0]` *after* the `xpath` call.

```
In [29]: doc.xpath('//head/link[@rel="image_src"]')[0]
Out[29]: <Element link at 9c94c5c>
```

---

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

url=r'http://www.yfrog.com/9d1truj'
doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
link=doc.xpath('//head/link[@rel="image_src"]/@href')[0]
print(link)
# http://img337.yfrog.com/img337/5023/1tru.jpg
```

Comment: I get this error:   File "yfrogparser.py", line 101, in extract_imageurl
    self.url, = doc.xpath('//head/link[@rel="image_src"]')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range